# Best Car Battery for Longevity in Extreme Heat

Tags: battery

I just had to replace my car battery after only 1 year of service.  The last battery I had before that died in about 18 months.  My car batteries die in the extreme heat during the summer when the temperatures are over 100 degrees Fahrenheit (37℃).  I live in the desert and it gets very hot here (New Mexico, USA).

I've been using O'Reily Autoparts Super Start battery.  My question is what car battery has been tested to perform the best in extreme heat conditions.  I am hoping to find a battery that can last at least three years.

Note:  In case you are wondering I had the charging system tested and it is not overcharging the battery.  I am pretty sure that it is the extreme heat that is killing it.  The battery does not die gracefully but dies rather sudden.  I've had oil changes where they tested the battery a week before it went dead and they said the battery was good.

Comment: Heat is a killer of all batteries, buy one with a good warranty, at least 2 years.

Comment: @Moab:  The Super Start batteries come with a two year warranty.  I was able to use the warranty for the battery that dies in 18 months.  The thing that bothers me the most is that there is no warning when the battery dies so I could be stranded in the middle of nowhere when it goes out.  I am thinking of just carrying a spare battery around all the time.

Comment: https://www.consumeraffairs.com/news/hot-weather-takes-a-toll-on-your-car-battery-071514.html

Comment: @DLH the spare will die also if stored in a hot vehicle.

Comment: How frequently do you check the electrolyte level in your battery? I can assume the liquid boils/evaporates faster when it is 100 degrees and very low humidity.